# What is the probability that 3 people share a same birthday in a room of n people?

Tags: probability

You are standing in a room with $n$ people.  What is the probability that three people have a birthday on the same day?

Maybe there is a general formula for the answer as a function of number of total people, $n$, and number of target people having the same birthday, but it seems rather complicated. Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem

Comment: i have read the wikipedia about the birthday problem, but i cannot find the general formula or the answer of this question. Where can i find it?

Comment: This problem should not be down-voted because (as far as I can see) the probability that $3$ people have the same birthday has not been posted on wikipedia or anywhere else easily accessed.  It is an interesting problem.

Comment: Perhaps it should be cleared up whether we should determine the probability of *exactly* three people sharing a birthday or that some day is the common birthday of *at least* three people.  The Question is on-hold for "missing context or other details", not because the formula has "been posted on [W]ikipedia" or elsewhere.